# Using Python Requests library to request Cookie as JSON in order to format as DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, cookies, python-requests, http-post

I'm trying to use Python Requests to retrieve a cookie from a website using a POST requests and JSON request parameters.

I'm using KNIME, which allows you to output a response as a DataFrame. When I request the cookie & attempt to output it as a DataFrame with the following code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import requests

session = requests.Session()

url = "https://api.danmurphys.com.au/apis/ui/Address/SetFavouriteStore"
payload = {"StoreNo":"1276"}

x = session.post(url, json=payload)

output_table = DataFrame(x.cookies)
```

, I get the following error:

```
Execute failed: No serializer extension having the id or processing python type "http.cookiejar.Cookie" could be found.
Unsupported column type in column: "0", column type: "<class 'http.cookiejar.Cookie'>".
```

I know the DataFrame output function would work if the response was JSON, so I've tried the following code:

```
x = session.post(url, json=payload)
res = session.cookies.get_dict()

output_table = DataFrame(res)
```

But this gives the following error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

If anyone knows how to format these cookies for DataFrame, or if I should be using a different library to Requests please inform me. Thanks.

EDIT: using the following DataFrame constructory:

```
output_table = DataFrame(data=session.cookies.get_dict(), index=session.cookies.get_dict(), columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
```

Is successful in outputting the cookies formatted as DataFrame however the values are replicated across rows and columns, as depicted in the screenshot. [image]

Comment: Can you explain where to put this line? I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Try to pass it into `DataFrame` constructor. It will return dict name/value.

Comment: Ok this worked to an extent, the following constructor: ```output_table = DataFrame(data=session.cookies.get_dict(), index=session.cookies.get_dict(), columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)```, but produces repeated values - I'll post a screenshot in my question to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ValueError points at passing all scalar values with an index, you may just do this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import requests

session = requests.Session()

url = "https://api.danmurphys.com.au/apis/ui/Address/SetFavouriteStore"
payload = {"StoreNo":"1276"}

x = session.post(url, json=payload)
res = session.cookies.get_dict()
output_table = DataFrame({'data':res})#pass res as a dictionary value
```